# Написание программ для PSP

Tags: java, книги, c++

Не подскажите, где искать информация для разработчиков программ для консоли PSP? На каких языках пишут программы для PSP? Я видел программу на C++. Есть ли возможность писать на Java?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее за все, что программы на "С" используют свой API.

Ваша Java программа может использовать либы "С". Но вот запускаться не будет. Для того, чтоб java программа могла запускаться на разных платформах, есть разные реализации JVM - виртуальной машины java под каждую платформу.

Но у вас всегда есть возможность написать свою JVM под PSP. Если не ошибаюсь спецификация открыта.

Comment: "у вас всегда есть возможность написать свою JVM под PSP." - да вы шутник :)